# can't handle Modernizr.backgroundsize with ie6 and some mobile devices

Tags: javascript, css, modernizr

I'm working in a mobile web application, there is a problem with some devices that doesn't support css3 and @media query,

i get the [css3-mediaqueries.js] to make all browsers support the media query, but my problem now is i need to check the devices that doesn't support some css3 features like background-size

i do some researches and i found the modernizer.js that can catch all devices that doesn't support the background-size

here is my HTML header

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Magrabi retail</title>
        <script src="js/modernizr.custom.02724.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/main.css" /> <!-- the main css that contain all css3 class -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" />
        <script src="js/css3-mediaqueries.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>



 Modernizr.load({
  test: Modernizr.backgroundsize,
  nope: 'css/main2.css' ,
 });

        </script>
    </head>
```

i do some tests in ie6 and in a mobile device that doesn't support css3 background-size and seems to be nothing different, only firefox 8 make the changes

just for note: i use the background-size for handle the high pixel density devices

Answer (score 0):

Modernizr does not enable support for background-size in browsers that don't natively support it. It just has a convenient cross-browser test for it, that tests for things like -moz-background-size and -ms-background-size. It's up to you to fake it when the test returns false.